# Guile foreign-library-function fails

Tags: linux, ffi, opensuse, dlopen, guile

In running an example from the guile handbook I stumbled upon an error while running `foreign-library-function`. It fails and prints a backtrace stating dlopen failed, because of an invalid elf format of the library. But the library is both present and working in other contexts.

The details to reproduce the issue:

`test.scm` (taken straight from the manual at https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.html#Foreign-Functions)

```
(define-module (math bessel)
  #:use-module (system foreign)
  #:use-module (system foreign-library)
  #:export (j0))

(define j0)
(foreign-library-function "libm" "j0"
                          #:return-type double
                          #:arg-types (list double))
```

If I execute `guile -s test.scm` I get the following output:

```
;;; note: source file /home/max/projects/guile-tests/test.scm
;;;       newer than compiled /home/max/.cache/guile/ccache/3.0-LE-8-4.5/home/max/projects/guile-tests/test.scm.go
;;; note: auto-compilation is enabled, set GUILE_AUTO_COMPILE=0
;;;       or pass the --no-auto-compile argument to disable.
;;; compiling /home/max/projects/guile-tests/test.scm
;;; compiled /home/max/.cache/guile/ccache/3.0-LE-8-4.5/home/max/projects/guile-tests/test.scm.go
Backtrace:
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
  1752:10  8 (with-exception-handler _ _ #:unwind? _ # _)
In unknown file:
           7 (apply-smob/0 #<thunk 7f57b930ef60>)
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
    724:2  6 (call-with-prompt _ _ #<procedure default-prompt-handle…>)
In ice-9/eval.scm:
    619:8  5 (_ #(#(#<directory (guile-user) 7f57b9307c80>)))
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
   2835:4  4 (save-module-excursion _)
  4380:12  3 (_)
In system/foreign-library.scm:
    240:6  2 (foreign-library-function "libm" "j0" #:return-type _ # …)
   190:25  1 (load-foreign-library _ #:extensions _ # _ #:search-path …)
In unknown file:
           0 (dlopen "/usr/lib64/libm.so" 1)

ERROR: In procedure dlopen:
In procedure dlopen: file "/usr/lib64/libm.so", message "/usr/lib64/libm.so: Ungültiger ELF-Header"
```

To ensure the file in question is actually there here's the output of `ls -la /usr/lib64/libm.so`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110 20. Jun 19:52 /usr/lib64/libm.so
```

The problem also occured for all other libraries I tried to adapt the snippet to.

My current system is running on

- openSUSE Tumbleweed 20210723
- with Linux kernel 5.22.3

I installed the `guile`-package using `zypper in guile` from the official repositories. (currently version 3.0.7)

I heavily suspect that openSUSEs compilation/linking settings could be at fault here, but can neither confirm nor invalidate that theory. - It would be ideal to both know why the issue occurs as well as knowing a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `dlopen: file "/usr/lib64/libm.so"`

I don't know anything about Guile, but the problem appears to be that it is trying to `dlopen` `libm.so`.

On Linux with GLIBC, `libm.so` is a linker script, not an ELF file. The *real* ELF library (and the library `guile` *should* be `dlopen`ing) is `libm.so.6`.

You can see that your `libm.so` (at 110 bytes) is way too small to be an ELF file. If you run `file -L /usr/lib64/libm.so*`, you should see something like this:

```
/usr/lib64/libm.so:   ASCII text
/usr/lib64/libm.so.6: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=07ae52cfc7f4eda1d13383c04564e3236e059993, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

Possibly you need to fix `system/foreign-library.scm` so it `dlopen`s correct library.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to make sense. - Thank you very much!
I just have to wonder why one of the most-advertised functionalities of the language would not work in such a standard case.

I'll investigate further and see whether I can meddle with foreign-library.scm to make it work and accept your answer once I'm sure that was the problem.

In any case, I'll probably file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem was that libm.so is a linker script, just like the other answer says.

The problem is resolved, if instead of "libm" one passes "libm.so.6" to the function.

The following is the corrected, working snippet.

```
(define-module (math bessel)
  #:use-module (system foreign)
  #:use-module (system foreign-library)
  #:export (j0))

(define j0)
(foreign-library-function "libm.so.6" "j0"
                          #:return-type double
                          #:arg-types (list double))
```